# Find a path from grid with rules

Tags: python, depth-first-search, breadth-first-search

I am learning bfs/dfs and trying to solve this question.
There is an n × n grid. Find a path (not necessarily the shortest path) that it will take to move from source cell to target cell within the grid, and return the path between these cells. There is a value for each grid cell. We can move in all four directions by one step a time: up, down , left, and right. We can only move to the adjacent cells that have equal or smaller value. If no move is possible to reach the target, return None.
Target is the right bottom corner, starting point the left top corner

```
input:
grid1 = [
[4,3,5],
[2,3,3],
[2,2,1]
]

output:
[4,3,3,2,1] or [4,2,2,2,1] or [4,3,3,2,2,2,1] or [4,3,3,3,1]
```

Below is my solution, but it seems the result mixed with the output result. Anyone can help me??

```
import collections
def findPath(grid):
    n = len(grid)
    seen = set()
    dirs = [(-1,0), (1,0), (0,1), (0,-1)]
    res = []
    queue = collections.deque()
    queue.append((0,0))
    res.append(grid[0][0])
    while queue:
        i,j = queue.popleft()
        for x,y in dirs:
            new_i = x + i
            new_j = y + j
            if new_i<0 or new_i>=n or new_j<0 or new_j>=n or grid[new_i][new_j] > grid[i][j]:
                continue
            if (new_i, new_j) in seen:
                continue
            # print((new_i,new_j))
            # print(grid[new_i][new_j])
            res.append(grid[new_i][new_j])
            if new_i==n-1 and new_j == n-1:
                return res
            seen.add((new_i, new_j))
            queue.append((new_i, new_j))
    return None
```

Comment: The problem is that you explore multiple paths and add cells from different paths to your `res` list. When you find a result you return the `res` list with cells from multiple paths. This problem can be solved easiest with recursion I think. Are you interested in a recursive solution?

Answer (score 0):

As I think this is a problem, where recursion is the easiest solution, I made an example implementation:

**Function to find all paths:**

```
def find_paths_recursive(grid, current_path=[(0,0)], solutions=[]):
    n = len(grid)
    dirs = [(-1,0), (1,0), (0,1), (0,-1)]
    
    last_cell = current_path[-1]
    
    for x,y in dirs:
        new_i = last_cell[0] + x
        new_j = last_cell[1] + y
        
        # Check if new cell is in grid
        if new_i<0 or new_i>=n or new_j<0 or new_j>=n:
            continue
            
        # Check if new cell has bigger value than last
        if grid[new_i][new_j] > grid[last_cell[0]][last_cell[1]]:
            continue
        
        # Check if new cell is already in path
        if (new_i, new_j) in current_path:
            continue

        # Add cell to current path
        current_path_copy = current_path.copy()
        current_path_copy.append((new_i, new_j))

        if new_i==n-1 and new_j == n-1:
            solutions.append(current_path_copy)
        
        # Create new current_path array for every direction
        find_paths_recursive(grid, current_path_copy, solutions)
        
    return solutions
```

**Function to get values of paths:**

```
def compute_cell_values(grid1, solutions):
    path_values = []

    for solution in solutions:
        solution_values = []
        for cell in solution:
            solution_values.append(grid1[cell[0]][cell[1]])
        path_values.append(solution_values)
    return path_values
```

**Example:**

```
grid1 = [
[4,3,5],
[2,3,3],
[2,2,1]
]


solutions = find_paths_recursive(grid1)
path_values = compute_cell_values(grid1, solutions)

print('Solutions:')
print(solutions)
print('Values:')
print(path_values)
```

**Example output:**

```
Solutions:
[[(0, 0), (1, 0), (2, 0), (2, 1), (2, 2)], [(0, 0), (0, 1), (1, 1), (2, 1), (2, 2)], [(0, 0), (0, 1), (1, 1), (1, 2), (2, 2)], [(0, 0), (0, 1), (1, 1), (1, 0), (2, 0), (2, 1), (2, 2)]]
Values:
[[4, 2, 2, 2, 1], [4, 3, 3, 2, 1], [4, 3, 3, 3, 1], [4, 3, 3, 2, 2, 2, 1]]
```

Note: It is important that the values which describe a cell in a path are not coordinates, but array indices. This means the first value of a cell is a y-value in your grid.

**EDIT:** As recursion is not always (or mostly not) the best solution and you had a good idea with the queue, I made another solution. The difference to your solution is that the queue stores the paths that we explore. It only gives back one path (if one exists), but it is the shortest one.

```
def find_path(grid):
    n = len(grid)
    dirs = [(-1,0), (1,0), (0,1), (0,-1)]
    queue = collections.deque()
    queue.append([(0,0)])
    
    while queue:
        current_path = queue.popleft()
        last_cell_i = current_path[-1][0]
        last_cell_j = current_path[-1][1]
        
        for x,y in dirs:
            new_i = x + last_cell_i
            new_j = y + last_cell_j
            
            # Check if new cell is in grid
            if new_i<0 or new_i>=n or new_j<0 or new_j>=n:
                continue
                
            # Check if new cell has bigger value than last
            if  grid[new_i][new_j] > grid[last_cell_i][last_cell_j]:
                continue
            
            # Check if new cell is already in path
            if (new_i, new_j) in current_path:
                continue
            
            # Add cell to current path
            current_path_copy = current_path.copy()
            current_path_copy.append((new_i, new_j))
        
            if new_i==n-1 and new_j == n-1:
                return current_path_copy
            
            queue.append(current_path_copy)
    return None
```