# Optimizing a path finding alg. from grid with rules

Tags: python, algorithm, optimization, path-finding

I'm trying to code a path finding algorithm, for this problem: You're given a grid with values, and your goal is to find the longest path from the highest point to the lowest point (least steep one).

I experimented with code I on here [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68464767/find-a-path-from-grid-with-rules], but for large grids (e.g. 140x140). Since the code is checking every single possible route, it's taking really long to calculate it. Could I implement any stopping solution that would just not continue finding the path is the path isn't optimal ?

As i said earlier, i found code on here that works, but is just way too slow for me to use. Here's my code with the grid. The code works perfectly for smaller grids.

The code below itsn't full, because the grid is too large to be posted here. The full code can be found here - https://pastebin.com/q4nKS4rS

```py
    def find_paths_recursive(grid, current_path=[(136,136)], solutions=[]):
    n = len(grid)
    dirs = [(-1,0), (1,0), (0,1), (0,-1)]
    
    last_cell = current_path[-1]
    
    for x,y in dirs:
        new_i = last_cell[0] + x
        new_j = last_cell[1] + y
        
        # Check if new cell is in grid
        if new_i<0 or new_i>=n or new_j<0 or new_j>=n:
            continue
            
        # Check if new cell has bigger value than last
        if grid[new_i][new_j] > grid[last_cell[0]][last_cell[1]]:
            continue
        
        # Check if new cell is already in path
        if (new_i, new_j) in current_path:
            continue

        # Add cell to current path
        current_path_copy = current_path.copy()
        current_path_copy.append((new_i, new_j))

        if new_i==0 and new_j ==0:
            solutions.append(current_path_copy)
        print(current_path_copy)
        # Create new current_path array for every direction
        find_paths_recursive(grid, current_path_copy, solutions)
        
    return solutions

def compute_cell_values(grid1, solutions):
    path_values = []

    for solution in solutions:
        solution_values = []
        for cell in solution:
            solution_values.append(grid1[cell[0]][cell[1]])
        path_values.append(solution_values)
    return path_values

grid1 = [...]


solutions = find_paths_recursive(grid1)
path_values = compute_cell_values(grid1, solutions)

print('Solutions:')
print(solutions)
print('Values:')
print(path_values)
```

Comment: *"from the highest point"*: your code starts at (0, 0). Is that what you mean with the "highest" point? The value at (0, 0) is 37 in your large grid, which seems to actually be the least value in the whole grid. Can you clarify what "highest" and "lowest" means?

Comment: Thank you for the notice, my bad. I edited the code now, so that it starts from [136,136], and goes to [0,0]. I'm aware that the code now work only for this grid now, but i really only care about the opimization side of things.

Comment: I think this is a NP-hard problem: for areas that have the same value you need to find ways to preferably include them all cells in that area in the path and end up in the next "plateau" where you need to do the same. There are too many possibilities to do this by just trying all possible paths, but there doesn't seem to be a solution that has polynomial time complexity.

Comment: Do you think multithreading would help ? Don't want to waste my time coding it if it would be for nothing.

Comment: No, I don't think it will help enough to bring the running time to an acceptable level.